# Dimensão de um vetor passado por referência linguagem C

Tags: c, array, funções, ponteiro, referência

Gostaria de saber como eu descubro a quantidade de posições que possui um vetor que foi passado por referência para a função, utilizando a linguagem C.

Exemplo (Protótipo de função):

```
int Soma (int *vetorValores)
{
   int i;
   int tamVetor = ??
   int total = 0;

   for (i=0;i<tamVetor;i++)
   {
        total+=vetorValores[i];
   }
   return total;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você possui o array no seu escopo, você pode usar a função sizeof pra descobrir o tamanho em bytes e usar divisão para calcular a quantidade de elementos, da seguinte maneira:

```
#define NUMERO_DE_ELEMENTOS 10
int arr[NUMERO_DE_ELEMENTOS];
tamanho_arr NumeroDeElementos= sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
```

Agora, se você esta passando o array como argumento de uma função (como você quer), não existe como você determinar o tamanho usando sizeof. Você terá que calcular isso antes de usar a sua função e depois passar esse número de elementos de alguma forma, por exemplo:

```
void suaFuncao(int* arr, int NumeroDeElementos)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < NumeroDeElementos; ++i) {

  /* faz o que você quiser aqui */
  arr[i] = /*...*/
  }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, querido. Acabei chegando a essa conclusão também após inúmeras pesquisas. Rs

Comment: A segunda forma foi exatamente a que fiz. Obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Fico feliz em ter ajudado! Valeu pelo feedback!